# Comment font size is smaller than others

Tags: bug, comments

This [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46319247/is-there-any-warning-for-writing-this-field-instead-of-this-field#comment79610851_46320297) font size looks smaller than others:

> [image: comment]

Tested in Chrome for Android. Possibly an Android issue.

Comment: Firefox nightly & Linux: it doesn't happen.