# Comments from OP have a different font size than comments from others

Tags: bug, comments, mobile-web, mobile-chrome

Comments from OP have a different font size than comments from others.

Example from [How can one get the clipboard menu item in the contextual menu in Gmail's compose email field?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/220076/12202):

[image]

Tested on Google Chrome on Samsung Galaxy S9 with Android 9 and with the "Desktop site" option activated in Google Chrome.

Comment: Under the same conditions, but with the S9+, I see that you are *class* (see source) `comment-user owner` and they are *class* `comment-user` - on my system your name has a light grey background while their's has no background - both fonts are the same size: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMWlz.jpg --- What about Visibility Enhancements?: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDYLp.jpg

Comment: Related: [Comment font size is smaller than others](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301277/289905).

Comment: This is specific to the mobile web view I believe. Responsive design works just fine. Expecting status-deferred in 6-8 time units, as the mobile web view is in the process if being phased out.

Comment: @Luuklag thanks, what do you mean by the responsive design works fine, and where was the phasing out of the mobile web view announced?

Comment: See comment from nick on this post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337797/blurry-text-on-stack-overflow-with-chrome The most recent example I could find. You could switch to full site in the footer, and then enable/disable responsive design in the footer as well. Works far more convenient then the mobile web version IMHO.

Comment: This one isn’t specific to Android, though. Voted to leave open.