# "Submit" is not an answer to the question "Does this answer your question?"

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, design, post-notices

"Submit" is not an answer to the question "Some community members have suggested a similar question that may solve your problem. Does this answer your question?"

[image: The dialog shown to you when your question has a vote to close it as a duplicate.]

Screenshot from Google Chrome on Samsung Galaxy S9 with Android 9 of the page [Comments from OP have a different font size than comments from others](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341681/178179).

Replacing "submit" with a yes/no choice seems more appropriate.

Comment: I think this might be a duplicate of [the new post notices announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339700/369802), see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339805/369802) there that already points out the same problem. It has a status-review tag.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell thanks good catch! Too bad it's locked

Comment: @Jenayah thanks, not really because the issue hasn't been addressed, the thread is locked and the issue is mentioned in an answer: this make it untrackable.

Comment: TBH I wasn't really asking, it's the new auto-generated dupe comment. In any case, as it's already been reported and marked [status-review], I do think it's better to dupe-close that question and leave it to be a trackable signpost.

Comment: @Jenayah ah I see you mean, sorry I hadn't realized that there was status-review in the answer itself. I agree with you.

Comment: I have [requested that the lock there be removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341818/the-historical-lock-on-the-new-post-notices-announcement-be-removed-and-replaced).

Comment: @Jenayah It makes no sense to close it at the moment, since it's historically locked and the answer there can't be tracked anymore. (Ordinarily I'd agree with such a closure, but...)

Comment: There's an official comment-response here, but I don't understand it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339700/new-post-notices-are-live-network-wide/339805#comment1143772_339805